# Stack smashing detected on file closing

Tags: c, file

I don't understand why it gives an error. Although everything reads from the file fine.
An arror *** stack smashing detected ***: terminated
Aborted (core dumped).

```
{
    FILE *set = fopen("data.bin", "rb");
    if (set == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "I/O ERROR: Can't read from file.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    int number;
    Enrollee e;
    fread(&number, sizeof(number), 1, set);
    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
        if (fread(&(e.id)           , sizeof(e.id)           , 1       , set) != 1       ) { fprintf(stderr, "I/O ERROR: Something went wrong! Failed to read, possibly out of memory\n"); exit(3); };
        if (fread(&(e.surname)      , sizeof(e.surname)      , STR_SIZE, set) != STR_SIZE) { fprintf(stderr, "I/O ERROR: Something went wrong! Failed to read, possibly out of memory\n"); exit(3); };
        if (fread(&(e.initials)     , sizeof(e.initials)     , STR_SIZE, set) != STR_SIZE) { fprintf(stderr, "I/O ERROR: Something went wrong! Failed to read, possibly out of memory\n"); exit(3); };
        if (fread(&(e.gender)       , sizeof(e.gender)       , 6       , set) != 6       ) { fprintf(stderr, "I/O ERROR: Something went wrong! Failed to read, possibly out of memory\n"); exit(3); };
        if (fread(&(e.schoolNumber) , sizeof(e.schoolNumber) , 1       , set) != 1       ) { fprintf(stderr, "I/O ERROR: Something went wrong! Failed to read, possibly out of memory\n"); exit(3); };
        if (fread(&(e.medal)        , sizeof(e.medal)        , 1       , set) != 1       ) { fprintf(stderr, "I/O ERROR: Something went wrong! Failed to read, possibly out of memory\n"); exit(3); };
        if (fread(&(e.essayResults) , sizeof(e.essayResults) , 1       , set) != 1       ) { fprintf(stderr, "I/O ERROR: Something went wrong! Failed to read, possibly out of memory\n"); exit(3); };
        if (fread(&(e.math)         , sizeof(e.math)         , 1       , set) != 1       ) { fprintf(stderr, "I/O ERROR: Something went wrong! Failed to read, possibly out of memory\n"); exit(3); };
        if (fread(&(e.language)     , sizeof(e.language)     , 1       , set) != 1       ) { fprintf(stderr, "I/O ERROR: Something went wrong! Failed to read, possibly out of memory\n"); exit(3); };
        if (fread(&(e.fisics)       , sizeof(e.fisics)       , 1       , set) != 1       ) { fprintf(stderr, "I/O ERROR: Something went wrong! Failed to read, possibly out of memory\n"); exit(3); };
        if (fread(&(e.informatics)  , sizeof(e.informatics)  , 1       , set) != 1       ) { fprintf(stderr, "I/O ERROR: Something went wrong! Failed to read, possibly out of memory\n"); exit(3); };
        if (fread(&(e.history)      , sizeof(e.history)      , 1       , set) != 1       ) { fprintf(stderr, "I/O ERROR: Something went wrong! Failed to read, possibly out of memory\n"); exit(3); };
        if (fread(&(e.socialScience), sizeof(e.socialScience), 1       , set) != 1       ) { fprintf(stderr, "I/O ERROR: Something went wrong! Failed to read, possibly out of memory\n"); exit(3); };
        if (fread(&(e.biology)      , sizeof(e.biology)      , 1       , set) != 1       ) { fprintf(stderr, "I/O ERROR: Something went wrong! Failed to read, possibly out of memory\n"); exit(3); };
        if (fread(&(e.chemistry)    , sizeof(e.chemistry)    , 1       , set) != 1       ) { fprintf(stderr, "I/O ERROR: Something went wrong! Failed to read, possibly out of memory\n"); exit(3); };
        printf("%d %.20s %.3s %.2s %d %c %c %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d\n",
        e.id,
        e.surname,
        e.initials,
        e.gender,
        e.schoolNumber,
        e.medal,
        e.essayResults,
        e.math, e.language, e.fisics, e.informatics, e.history, e.socialScience, e.biology, e.chemistry);
    }
    fseek(set, 0, 0);
    fclose(set);
}
```

Comment: Please post [mcve]. BTW, have you noticed the code enormous code replication, which is also making your code hard to read? Take the error handling into a separate function.

Comment: Without knowing the definition of Enrollee it is hard to tell. But I would focus on the strings, your reading of them assumes that `sizeof(e.surname)==1` which is probably not true. fread multiplies `size` and `nmemb` together and reads that many bytes.

Comment: This looks wrong: `sizeof(e.surname)      , STR_SIZE,` but without the definition of `Enrollee ` we can't tell

Comment: This code smashes the stack when it freads more than fits in Enrollee.  e.initials can't be good, 6 genders seems to be off.

Comment: Why did you remove the comment that show the definition  of `Enrollee` ? Please edit your question and insert  it.

Answer (score 0):

All your string reading are wrong.

```
fread(&(e.gender)       , sizeof(e.gender)       , 6       , set)
```

says: Read 6 elements. Each element is `sizeof(e.gender)` bytes.

Since `gender` is an array, i.e. `char gender[6]`, `sizeof(e.gender)` returns 6.

So your code reads 6 * 6 = 36 bytes. You only wanted 6.

Do:

```
fread(&(e.gender)       , sizeof(char)       , 6       , set)
```

or better

```
fread(&(e.gender)       , sizeof(gender[0])       , sizeof(gender)       , set)
```

This applies to all yours strings.